# JSDoc: Trying to use @typedef with a generic @callback

Tags: javascript, generics, typedef, jsdoc

I am somewhat new to JSDoc, but I am trying to define a typedef that has a generically-typed function (the return type is inferred from the param type).

It seems like the following code should result in the type of the `bar` constant to be `string`. Instead I am getting an `any` type.

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @callback MyFunction
 * @param {T} val
 * @return {T}
 */

/**
 * @typedef MyType
 * @property {MyFunction} myFunction
 */

/** @type {MyType} */
const foo = {};
const bar = foo.myFunction('a string');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should specify generic type for `myFunction` property:

```js
/**
 * @typedef MyType
 * @property {MyFunction<string>} myFunction
 */
```

or you can make `MyType` generic too

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef MyType
 * @property {MyFunction<T>} myFunction
 */
```

but then you should specify generic type when define type for foo:

```js
/** @type {MyType<string>} */
const foo = {};
const bar = foo.myFunction('a string');

// OR
/** @type {MyType<string|number>} */
const foo = {};
const bar = foo.myFunction('a string');
```